# Zend Framework Integration with XAMPP

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-7, zend-form, xampp

I have been trying to integrate zend framework with xampp. But unable to achieve anything.

```
E:\Program Files\XAMPP\xampp\php\PEAR
```

Delete my zend library from the above path

Currently zend framework is available in

```
G:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\ZendFramework-1.11.11
```

I also tried to add the zend library from

```
G:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library
```

to

```
E:\Program Files\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\testproject\library
```

But, still whenever i just try to open my page by this URL

```
http://localhost:85/testproject/public/
```

I got an output of welcome to zendframework

But, whenever I just try to open any page where i used zend library like ZEND_FORM then I get an exception

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Form' not found in E:\Program Files\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\testproject\public\Guestbook.php on line 15
```

I have also updated my php.ini file and reverted my include_path to this

```
include_path = ".;E:\Program Files\XAMPP\xampp\php\PEAR;G:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library\"
```

Urgent help will be highly appreciated

My OS is windows 7.

When i entered a command php -v then it returned me

```
PHP 5.3.0 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2009 21:08:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

and zf show version returned me

```
zf show version
Zend Framework Version: 1.11.11
```

Version of xampp is 1.7.2

Appache version is :

```
Apache/2.2.12 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.0 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
```

**Index.php File**

```
<?php
// Set the initial include_path. You may need to change this to ensure that 
// Zend Framework is in the include_path; additionally, for performance 
// reasons, it's best to move this to your web server configuration or php.ini 
// for production.
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';  

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV, 
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();
$application->run();
    enter code here
```

**.htaccess File**

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Have you tried, after you created the project, to put the zend framework library in the library folder of your project?

Comment: What I don't understand is why you do all this things. To have ZF work, you have just to install XAMP, put the ZF unzipped folder into localhost, run the zf.bat to create your project and then copy/paste the ZF library into your project folder. After that you have to change a rule into your http.conf and that is change AllowOverride None into AllowOverride All

Comment: Tried but wasn't helpful still the same error :(

Comment: Post the source of your .htaccess file and index.php

Comment: I have updated my question and included both the files u asked me for.

Comment: Lose the slash at the end of your `php.ini` `include_path`

Comment: I have tested it with xamp, wamp, zend server and all the time i found similar issue. Btw Phil I have deleted slash from php.ini include_path but didn't find that helpful.

Comment: Check your http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help, i am using EasyPhp(instead of XAMPP)
and zend's auto generated .htaccess and i have this in apache

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost abc:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/www/www/abc/public"
ServerName .local
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
<Directory "C:/www/www/abc/public">

    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride All

    Order allow,deny

    Allow from all
</Directory> 

</VirtualHost>
```

and this is what the directory look like

```
 Directory di c:\www\www\abc

[.]              [..]             .buildpath       .project
[.settings]      .zfproject.xml   [application]    [cache]
[data]           [docs]           [library]        [public]
[scripts]        [tests]

 Directory di c:\www\www\abc\library

[.]          [..]         [abc] [tcpdf]      [Zend]       [ZendX]
```